# Is there a way of sharing the love?

Tags: discussion

If I found a more efficient way of coding a problem or using a cool tool, that would help other fellow developers, how would I share the love?  Or is this outside the remit of SO?

Answer (score 4):

If the tool can assist in the solving of an existing question you can post this as part of your answer, but NOT as the sole answer.

Outright Spam of a product will be deleted and could cost you a 100 reputations points of reported as such by other users. However we do accept that often a third party product could potentially be a solution, unless the question is asking for a particular product.

[Eric's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18424/is-there-a-way-of-sharing-the-love/18427#18427) answer is also a good option as long as it is within the context of a problem and a solution, and how it was solved. Also making it CW will ensure it is not considered spam or vote gaming by the community.

Comment: That's quite the **bold** answer.

Comment: I am trying to **make** a point. I have finally learned people miss the **key** parts of the answers and then comment/vote without **thinking** :)

Comment: assist in existing question NOT sole answer Spam do accept a third party product a solution particular product problem solution making it CW spam or vote gaming - I'm searching my key. It's broken in parts!

Comment: I give in. I should have learned MSO is the one place no one ever wins. Meta **is** murder :)

Comment: At first, I thought, "Oh, sweet, Diago linked one of my answers!" and then I was filled with disappointment. Damn you and your false hope, Diago.

Comment: The third party product was just an example. The main point is that if you have stuff so share, that could benefit other developers with their work, can you use SO to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

One sort of approach would be to simply post a question with an answer.  For example, post a question "What's your favorite program for X?"  Mark it as community wiki.  Then add your personal favorite as one of the answers.

Comment: +1 As long as it is within the context of a problem and a solution, and how it was solved.

Comment: It's common to only mark your own answer as community wiki in these situations.  That way anyone else answering can still get reputation points for coming up with alternate solutions, and you can still get a few stray points for the question if other people find it useful.

Comment: @Bill: I think that's a better approach, but the community wiki police sometimes don't like those kinds of subjective questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble across a great piece of information that you want to share, but which doesn't answer an existing problem, you could try:

blogging it

twittering it

or you could wait until someone asks a question to which you have the answer.